# Creating a comment section in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, comments

I'm looking for any information on how to create a comment system, like Facebook or whatever, and I am having trouble finding one. The word "comment" is too ubiquitous to return any useful info and I have never seen anything that covered this topic so I have no starting point. Any help would be appreciated as I feel like I am going about this in an overly complicated way. I plan to download the comments from Parse, then I assumed I would put them into an Array in my app. Then update something like commentLabel.text to whatever is in the Array. If so how would you go about doing this? Would it be something like:

```
let comment = [String]
```

Then fill the array with comments from Parse and then something like:

```
for comments in comment { 

  var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
  label.text = comments
  self.view.addSubview(label)

}
```

I know that code is incomplete. I'm basically just asking if that's the way to do it and it seems like it would be, but then how do you go about making sure the labels are created at the correct position, just below the previous comment for example, and how do you ensure the CGRect adjusts to the text provided? I'm really struggling with this concept. If this is the correct way to do this, I'll muddle through it but I want to make sure that there's not some much simpler way that I have just not been able to find. Thanks.

Comment: looks like you should take a look at UITableViews...! Or auto layout.

Comment: Using a UITableView was actually my first idea, which is why I summarily dismissed it. If I thought of it, then it couldn't be right, but that's two OTHER people confirming it so I'll do it that way. Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need some sort of backend. Most people have a database(mysql, postgres, etc) and a server-sided language orientated API that connects to the database. In my own experience, I typically use python + flask to create a RESTful API that connects to the database. This way, you can use URLs to transfer data such as usernames, passwords, etc.

Then, from there I'd assign something that shows what "post" the comments belong to. For example, a post id.

`GET api/posts/comments/<post_id>`

GET request that gets the comments related to post_id. This example shows a database named, "posts", a table named, "comments" and a column named, "post_id".

Now for swift, you'd have to send data through the URLs you made. You cant make a comment system with directly swift. You need some sort of backend to store your data in. Thus, you can then loop through the data and create UI elements with the contents of the loop.

Hope this was somewhat helpful. Probably not the most efficient but this is personally what I do.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to create multi level comment section. This link helped me, hope it helps you too.

https://flyingmoose.co/blog/ios/collapsible-comments-feed-in-swift.html

Basically it creates a constraint outlet for left margin and according to level of comment it increase or decrease the left margin for comment cell.

It also explains how to hide and expand lower level comments, simply by adding and deleting them from comments array at proper index.